# why doesn't my div take up the full width? Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-red-300">
    <div class="container h-12 mx-auto px-5 bg-gray-400">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make my div occupy the maximum width with tailwind but I can't

Comment: how about `w-screen`? relevant docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width

Answer (score 0):

Add the `min-w-full` class to your div, like this:

```
<div class="container h-12 mx-auto px-5 bg-gray-400 min-w-full"></div>
```

Here you can see how the classes are working:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/ynFuLYAVaG